# Windows Phone - Pushpin + Context Menu + multiple items per Pushpin

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, dictionary, contextmenu, pushpin

So my issue is this:
I have a map control that creates a number of pushpins based on the co-ords specified in each object. Inside each pushpin I use a context menu control in order to display the name of the item when the user holds their finger on the pushpin. My problem arises when I have two items that share the exact same co-ordinates. From what I can see basically the last item to get created becomes the top pushpin and hides the one underneath it. So when I click on the pushpin I only see the context menu name for that item, not the one underneath. What I want to do is for the two items to share the one pushpin if they have identical co-ords, and then when i press down on the pushpin for them both to appear in a contextmenu list.

But I'm totally stumped. Does the pushpin control maybe have a method that merges pushpins if within a certain distance of one another? Im guessing the solution will be a little bit more difficult than that!

Comment: If you are adding the pushpins programmatically, can you not perform some processing prior to adding the pushpins to achieve the "grouped" effect you are looking for?

Comment: Hi ya, All the controls are added within the xaml, not in the code-behind, but ya may need to look into moving some of it to the code-behind to enable me to merge them. just thought there might be a cleaner way.